# How to create a template archetype for nodeJs projects

Tags: javascript, node.js, maven, npm

New to node.js framework . I want to create a template archetype for a node.js project (create basic folders , config files ...) so that others can use this archetype to create their projects using this template, which will have all the basic folder structures and files from the archetype.

Can we use maven to create archetype for node.js projects ?. or some other open source tools are available? . If anyone has expertise on node.js frameworks please advise . Thanks in advance .

Comment: You are new to node.js and want to create a framework for other developers?

Comment: I just to learn things . I know how to generate archetypes in maven , just wondering , how we do it in case of node.js projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) what you're looking for? It is primarily for web applications, and it does do project templating, among things.

Comment: I guess this may help . I'll definitely try . Thanks